# vmware ESXi host disconnects intermittently

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, esxi, vcenter

Our remote ESXi host disconnects intermittently from our vCenter Server. 
I have tried increasing the timeout limit within the vCenter server 
but the problem still persists and the disconnects are more constant.

We tried searching all over internet and seems like this bug is uncorrectable?

Is there another way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Normally hosts intermittently disconnecting is due to a missing firewall rule for UDP traffic on port 902, bi-directionally, between the host and vCenter servers.